# content goes off-screen (HTML CSS)

Tags: html, css

As comments are added, the picture and the text goes out of bounds up, how to make sure that the image does not move and the new text increases the scrolling of the screen down, and does not move the text and image up. Thanks

```
{% for post in posts %}
       
       <div>
       <p>   <img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{post.photo.url}}" alt =  "barbaers" 
        width="1000" /> </p>
      </div>

          <h3>
        {{post.name_barber}} 
          </h3>
     <p>{{ post.description}}</p>



     <h3> Comments.. </h3>
    <a href="{% url 'post_detail' post.pk %}">Add comment</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    {% if not post.comments.all %}
    no comments yet...
  
    {% else %}

 
        {% for comment in post.comments.all %}

    <strong>
        {{comment.name}} -
        {{comment.add_date}}
    </strong>
        <p>{{comment.body }}</p>
        {% endfor %}            
    {% endif %}                     
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could include all this in one `<div>` and set the width and height to the bounds you want. Also you can the z-index to 2 so it is in front of everything else.